# Can I let my RPi power off randomly?

Tags: power-supply

I am placing my Raspberry Pi 4 in an embedded application on my boat.  I am using a PICAN-M HAT to provide both connectivity to the NMEA2000 backbone, as well as power to the Pi (5v 3A).

The NMEA2000 backbone is powered on by a switch on the DC power panel.  Under normal situations, this will be off unless there is a need for the navigation equipment, when it will be turned on.

Therefore, when the switch is turned on, all of the navigation equipment will turn on including the RPi, and when the switch is turned off everything shuts down including the RPi.  This is correct behavior.

Is this OK for the RPi?  It will not be shutdown using any "safe" mechanism, the power will just simply be yanked.

I have an SSD attached via USB, so can I just make the boot and root partitions read only, and the SSD as rw?  This would mean that the boot and root partitions wouldn't have any chance of being corrupted, and the SSD can protect itself using journaling.

Thoughts?  Is this a reasonable approach?  Any other ideas?

Simpler the better; this is essentially operating as an embedded device.

Comment: *"This would mean that the boot and root partitions wouldn't have any chance of being corrupted"* -> Pretty sure over the years there has been more than one person reporting corruption even with a RO filesystem.  I imagine this has to do with free play in the SD protocol, or possibly fluctuating current in a brown out causing a problem.  Don't let that scare you, but you will probably have less headaches if you can arrange a proper shutdown than you will with a RO system.

Comment: @goldilocks There's no way for a proper shutdown that I am aware of; the power is simply cut, and there is no opportunity to perform any sort of shutdown.  My hope is to create an `initramfs` root filesystem overlaying the RO root filesystem, so no changes will ever be sent to the root drive, which will be Readonly.  This seems the best I can do to mitigate problems.  I'll use a 32Gb microsd card as boot/root, and copy it, so even if for some reason the microsd card gets corrupted (even though it is RO), I can just pop in the backup and it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Removing power from the Pi without software shutdown risks corrupting the SD card and any connected disks.

The risk is increased if the SD card or disk is being written as the power is removed.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple (and well documented) to implement a shutdown on a GPIO signal.

I use `dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown,gpio_pin=21` and when BCM 21 (pin 40) is connected to Gnd the Pi shuts down.

There are also hardware solutions (including battery power) to detect power loss and gracefully shutdown the Pi.

It is simple to manually shutdown the Pi by pushing a button - all you need to do is develop a process, after all you don't cut the power on a boat without ensuring mooring lines are secure.

If you just cut power (provided the Pi is not busy) 99% of the time you will have no problem.

Comment: This is being used on a 35' rental sailboat.  When the renters are done, they often simply turn off the battery switch (to ensure nothing drains the boat batteries).  Just like that, power goes out in all onboard electronics, including the RaspberryPi.  So, no opportunity for graceful shutdown.  I'm trying to figure out a solution so my RaspberryPi is resilient against powerloss.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should avoid ***un***-**safe** shutdowns; i.e. pulling power while it is running. A ***safe*** shutdown halts the processor ***before*** removing power (via `halt`, `shutdown` or `poweroff` commands).

You can avoid this in your setup, but it will take more effort on your part. This additional effort could be accomplished **manually** with a second switch, ***or*** it could **automated** to happen automatically with additional circuitry/hardware. I've looked at the **PICAN-M HAT**, and disappointingly (according to the documentation) it makes no provisions for **safe** shutdown, despite the fact that it includes a power supply. For a $100 HAT, this strikes me as an amateurish design!

Your comment about *simpler is better* leads me to believe that you're not keen on an **automated** solution, and the presence of the **PICAN-M HAT** would complicate an automated solution. Therefore, the most feasible solution I see for you is to manually issue a `halt` command (i.e. `sudo halt`) via the command line before you flip the power switch.

Comment: This is being used on a 35' rental sailboat.  When the renters are done, they often simply turn off the battery switch (to ensure nothing drains the boat batteries).  Just like that, power goes out in all onboard electronics, including the RaspberryPi.  So, no opportunity for graceful shutdown.  I'm trying to figure out a solution so my RaspberryPi is resilient against powerloss.

Comment: @ToastySailor: Are you more interested in a solution you purchase - or in one you make yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem - using an RPi 4 with OpenPlotter and the PICAN-M HAT. I’d love to find a way to wire a hard shutdown button but the PICAN-M does not pass through the GPIO PINs. My workaround for now is to run a web server on the Pi with a link to a PHP script to do a shutdown. I access it using the WiFi Hotspot on the Pi from any mobile device with a browser. Not perfect but it’s easy enough to do it from the cockpit before I dock and turn the NMEA power off.